# Drawing line that is tangent to two circles in ArcGIS?

Tags: arcgis-pro, polyline-creation

I have a series of not-quite parallel lines (stream transects) that I need to put into ArcGIS.  The initial plan was to gather coordinates with GPS but topography, etc has eliminated that option.  In the field the distance from the left-end of each transect to the left-end of the next transect was measured as was the distance from the right-end of the transect to the right-end of the next transect.  I also know the lengths of all the transects.

I think I know (but have never been good at proofs) that the second transect should be a line that is tangential to the two circles I could draw using the measured distances at the ends of the first transect as radii.  When I used AutoCAD I could have created a line tangential to both circles (handy for best-fitting centerline descriptions) but I can't find that in ArcGIS Pro.  (My most recent ESRI proficiency was approximately ArcGIS Desktop 10.4 - and don't think I ever looked for it there.)

In the long run it is not imperative that I tie the transects tightly to real locations but I need a good sketch for analyzing other features and events that I can locate on the transects.

[image: horizontal line with circle centered on each end and another not quite parallel line that is tangent to both circles above horizontal line]

Comment: If you only know lengths of 4 sides, number of solutions is countless. You need at least 3 pairs of coordinates.

Comment: Looks like a segment of the convex hull of the two circles

Comment: So you want to create the dashed blue line from the orange line? Do you have encoded into the line (or some point dataset) the radius of the two circles? How many dashed lines do you want to create, millions or just a few?

Comment: @Hornbydd Yes, I am trying to create/draw the dashed blue line having drawn the orange line.  I have a spreadsheet of transect lengths, distances from each transect end to next transect corresponding end (which I think I should use as radii (arrows) to create green circles), and 2 intermediate distances (1/3 and 2/3 from left end where I could place a vertex) along the transect where additional distances to next transect were measured (solid blue lines).  There are about 40 of these transects in a set.

Comment: @FelixIP Yes, 4 sides aren't enough, but if a tan-tan line could be drawn wouldn't it be the length of the next transect?  And be forced to correct angle relative to first line?

Comment: It will be a known length, but will it match the one you measured?

Comment: @FelixIP My instincts say yes, but I never got the hang of remembering theorems or writing proofs (I lean towards if A then G rather than if A then B then C then....)  I'd know one way or the other if I could get ArcGIS to do what I want! ;-)

Comment: In the snap tool there is an option to snap to tangent.  While it doesn't always seem to work, in 2.9 it mostly works.  The only problem is that it's iterative for a few times because each time you move one end that changes the tangent of the other end, but you can get there usually after 3-4 re-placements of each vertex.

A QC check may show an extra vertex on the line, indicating a chord, but if you investigate you will see it's not, it's before point of tangency.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to do iterations, using idea of BERA.
So, to create 2nd section:

```
arcpy.FeatureVerticesToPoints_management(in_features="sections", out_feature_class="in_memory/ENDS", point_location="BOTH_ENDS")
arcpy.Buffer_analysis(in_features="ENDS", out_feature_class="in_memory/CIRCLES", buffer_distance_or_field="LENGTH", line_side="FULL", line_end_type="ROUND", dissolve_option="ALL", dissolve_field="", method="PLANAR")
arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(in_features="CIRCLES", out_feature_class="in_memory/VICTIM", config_keyword="", spatial_grid_1="0", spatial_grid_2="0", spatial_grid_3="0")
arcpy.CalculateField_management(in_table="VICTIM", field="Shape", expression="!Shape!.convexHull()", expression_type="PYTHON_9.3", code_block="")
```

will result in:

[image]

These:

```
arcpy.Erase_analysis(in_features="VICTIM", erase_features="CIRCLES", out_feature_class="in_memory/VICTIM_Erase", cluster_tolerance="")
arcpy.FeatureVerticesToPoints_management(in_features="VICTIM_Erase", out_feature_class="in_memory/all_vertices", point_location="ALL")
arcpy.PolygonToLine_management(in_features="VICTIM", out_feature_class="in_memory/outline", neighbor_option="IDENTIFY_NEIGHBORS")
arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management(in_layer="all_vertices", overlap_type="INTERSECT", select_features="outline", search_distance="0.001 Meters", selection_type="NEW_SELECTION", invert_spatial_relationship="INVERT")
```

result in:

[image]

You can delete selected point. You might also want to delete duplicate points, because there is one. Pick direction and construct draft of your second section. Expand/shrink (by equal amount from center point) your second section to it's measured length:

[image]

Proceed with 3rd, etc...
It is scriptable, because direction can be defined as "keep child section that is on a left side of parent".